# Get bundle id from p12/pem file

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, pem, pkcs#12

Is it possible to get application's bundle id from p12/pem file for APNS?

I have a system where user can upload his push certificate (p12 or pem) and would be great to show him an info about bundle id so user will be able to check what he uploaded

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it's 100% helpful but you can use command line tool from openssl library in the following manner

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in mycert.p12 -passin pass:MyCertPassPhrase
```

this will produce the output you can parse

```
MAC Iteration 1
MAC verified OK
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 2048
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: Apple Production IOS Push Services: com.mybundle.domain
    localKeyID: F2 FZ 5D 00 44 73 F1 64 B8 FF EF 37 82 BC 13 F4 81 6A B2 14 
subject=/UID=com.mybundle.domain/CN=Apple Production IOS Push Services: com.mybundle.domain/OU=Q7QX7A5JZ7/C=RU
issuer=/C=US/O=Apple Inc./OU=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations/CN=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFeTCCBGGgAwIBAgIILW8Tn/Z054IwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwgZYxCzAJBgNV
```

where com.mybundle.domain is what you're looking for.

Comment: How do we do that in java, any idea?