# Unable to get configuration file for implementing Push Notification using GCM in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I repeatedly get the error:- "The Bundle ID in the certificate does not match the Bundle ID you entered."

I have gone through following link:-
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/certs#create_the_ssl_certificate

Also verified my bundle id using:-
openssl pkcs12 -info -in mycert.p12 -passin pass:MyCertPassPhrase

i got above from following link:-[Get bundle id from p12/pem file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29171097/get-bundle-id-from-p12-pem-file)

but still get the same error even though my bundle id matches.Please suggest a solution or alternative to accomplish the same.

Let me know in case additional information is needed.

[image: Screenshot is as follows:-]

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was exporting both certificate and key together to p12 (as it should be done). There was some issue with signing identities so after 7-8 tries, doing the same thing worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Leave "CA Email Address" empty while creating "CertificateSigningRequest" certificate. This fixed my problem.